# Boto3 client upload_fileobj throws error NoSuchBucket

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to upload a file to my bucket i.e. `test-bucket`...
So, I specified a constant `AWS_S3_BUCKET="test-bucket"` and defined the next function (from a some tutorial or forum):

```
import boto3
from config import AWS_S3_LOCATION


s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def upload_file_to_s3(file, bucket_name, acl="public-read"):#bucket_name=AWS_S3_BUCKET
    try:
        s3.upload_fileobj(
            file,
            bucket_name,
            file.filename,
            ExtraArgs={
                "ACL": acl,
                "ContentType": file.content_type
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print("Something Happened: ", e)
        return e
    return "{}{}".format(AWS_S3_LOCATION, file.filename)
```

My **config.py**:

```
import os

AWS_S3_BUCKET = os.environ['AWS_S3_BUCKET']
AWS_S3_LOCATION = 'http://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/'.format(AWS_S3_BUCKET)

DEBUG = True
PORT = 5000
```

I have installed AWS Cli where I setup `aws_access_key`, `aws_secret_access_key` and `region` (`eu-west-1`).
But when I try to upload a file I get an error:

```
An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
{'Error': {'Code': 'NoSuchBucket', 'Message': 'The specified bucket does not exist', 'BucketName': 'test-bucket'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'blah-blah', 'HostId': 'blah-blah', 'HTTPStatusCode': 404, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-request-id': 'blah-blah', 'x-amz-id-2': 'blah-blah', 'content-type': 'application/xml', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'date': 'Sun, 01 Apr 2018 21:59:44 GMT', 'connection': 'close', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

What can be wrong?

**ADDED**
Uploading from the terminal using AWS CLI works:
`aws s3api put-object --bucket test-bucket --key test.txt --body test.txt`

**ADDEDv2**
I didn't understand what happened but after I sent a file from the terminal, my app became to work too. I chose a same file like before.

Comment: Double-check that the region in your config file is the same one as the one where you created the bucket. Also check that the region is in the profile `[default]` so that it is selected.

Comment: @RomanKutlak sorry, but I am learning only how to work with S3... Can u explain more? Sorry, I got a nothing almost... Where should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is the region. If you installed the CLI, you probably have the credentials and the config in your home folder in .aws on unix, not sure where on windows [here is more info on the config files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html). Your config should have the region:
.aws/config:

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
```

If you created the bucket using the web interface, your region is in the top right corner. I think by default it is North Virginia which corresponds to us-east-1 [(full list here)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html). You probably want to select Ireland.

The config file allows you to have multiple profiles (e.g., dev and prd) [more here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html)

Comment: I am on linux... Yeah, it's set so I have checked just now. I created my bucket using Web UI but I chose Europe Ireland, so it's `eu-west-1`

Comment: I tried to upload a file from AWS CLI, it works perfectly... So AWS CLI configuration is right

Answer (score -1):

Didn't you forget AWS_S3_BUCKET in your import line? Currently it only says: `from config import AWS_S3_LOCATION`

Comment: This constant is used to return URL only.

Comment: @Шах `def upload_file_to_s3(file, bucket_name, acl="public-read"):#bucket_name=AWS_S3_BUCKET` seems to suggest you used the constant to set the bucket_name which was why i suggested it was missing